# NSDateFormatter returning null in iOS5.0, iOS6.0

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am getting a string from server which I am converting to date. Below is the code I am using.

```
NSString *endDateString = @"2014-03-01T00:00:00-08:00";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *eventEndDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endDateString];
NSLog(@"%@", eventEndDate);
```

It's running fine in iOS7.0, but giving me a NULL in iOS 5.0 and 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format is wrong for timeline offset with an embedded ":".

Use:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

From: ICU [Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

[image]

Comment: Except that ZZZZZ is new, and I'm not sure how far back it's supported.

Comment: @Hot At least to iOS6, I just tried it. I am aware this used to be a problem.

Comment: @Hot Interestingly iOS7 even supports the new "X" and "V" ISO8601 formats.